# How to create a dotted border line inside an html table

Tags: html

I created a function that generates an html table filled with data that I read from a file. The boarders of the table and so on are fixed and set but the data inside is dynamic and is read on the fly - just as the creating of the cell. Here is the code used for crerating and formatting the cell:

```
<td nowrap align="right" style="border-left:dotted 2px #000000">
   <font face="arial" size="2" color="#000000">  text here </font>
</td>
```

The problem is that since every cell is created separately the dotting on top and botted joins, making a longer line. Is there any way to change this?

If not - is there any way to format it in general table properties (the problem is it's just one border inside the table that I want dotted - the rest should be solid with different width, and when done to each and every cell separatedly it looks just fine).

I already tried to find an answer online, but the tutorial seems to overlook such issue.

EDIT:

I added a picture showing the current result. The  border-collapse didn't bring wanted results: (this is a close-up to the cells of two consecute rows)

[image]

Comment: jsfiddle.net and an embedded image of what you want and what you get is appriciated

Comment: in the code, u only have left border while in the question, u mention top and bottom

Comment: I meant the top and bottom of the left border - the bottom of the left border of cell 1 glues with the top of the left border of cell 2 creating a longer line instead of a dot. I tried to create a fiddle but it looks good on it. I also just tried it in firefox and it looks good as well - the problem is when I open it in IE so I am really confused right now

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the border-collapse property on the table

http://jsfiddle.net/L3v2P/2/

```
.dotted{
    border: dotted 3px #000000;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;/*This property collapses borders together*/
}
```

Comment: How to do so without the usage of css?

Comment: What do you mean? How can you not use CSS here?

Comment: I have never used css before and i dont know how to embed it in my html file :/

Comment: Within style tags or using an external file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" />`

Comment: @max just paste the css inline

Comment: Ok, I made some attempts and now know what's wrong - it does work only on firefox, on other browsers (like chrome) it is still not good - screen: http://imgur.com/rJZtQDX